# pass value from ajax to node via post

Tags: node.js, express

I've gone through the responses on this and haven't been able to figure it out.  I'm trying to pass some data from a file to a url which is running a node express server.  I have no previous knowledge on this so I'm sure I'm messing up something.

Here is my ajax call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#preview_btn").click(function(event) {
      if($("#user_input").val() == ""){
         return false;
      }

    var tsid = "Hello there, you big bad server you...";

    $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {str: tsid},
  url: 'https://myurl.com/preview/node-webshot/testing',
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  }
}); 
});
});
```

Here is my server.js file located in node-webshot directory on the server.
I tried:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.post('/testing', function(req,res){
    let inputContent = req.body.textField;
    console.log(inputContent);
});

app.listen(8000);
```

And this based on another answer:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.post('/testing', function(req, res) {
  var obj = {};
  console.log('body' + JSON.strigify(req.body));
  res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I click the preview button which calls the ajax function I get

```
node-webshot/testing 404 (Not Found)
```

I also ensure the server.js file is fired up on the server.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You are getting 404, because you are sending POST request to the wrong URL. File location has nothing to do with API URL. Probably your URL has to look like this - `https://myurl.com/testing` (server URL + path)

Comment: It is the correct url this is server plus path: https://myurl.com/preview/node-webshot/testing @Volodymyr